# Generating Bokeh html files that work offline

Tags: python, html, bokeh, offline

In the past it seems **bokeh** had options to generate html files that work offline. Here is an older discussion that shows how to do it:
https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/bokeh/Ts2P24YR0VU

using the line:

```
output_file(file_path, mode='inline')
```

However, this seem not to work with the **bokeh** version I am using `0.12.10`

When I try adding `mode = 'inline'` I am getting:

```
TypeError: file_html() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mode'
```

Looking at the new dcumentaion it makes sense:
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/embed.html#bokeh.embed.file_html

Is it possible to get a short example of what to do to allow the html files to be viewed offline without running a local **bokeh** server?

Hopefully the solution is trivial as before.

Jacob

Comment: Running an example with `output_file(path, mode='inline')` on Bokeh 0.13 works perfectly as expected for me. As requested for SO questions, please supply a *complete, minimal, reproducing example*.

Comment: To bigreddot: The documentation link does not even show the mode argument - this is consistent with the error I am getting. Arguments allowed are: models, resources, title, template, template_variables, theme . Are you sure you are using version 13?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Your link above is to the wrong place.  The docs for `output_file` are here: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/io.html#bokeh.io.output_file and do show the mode parameter. You are linking to the low level `file_html` function which is not the same thing, and not what you need to use.

Comment: Thanks bigreddot, You are right. I was confusing file_html with output_file without even noticing it - copy and paste error - I just used the mode in file_html and therefore the confusion. Many thanks for straining me out. By the way, any idea how to make the html file work offline with file_html so I can add html text to the file before plotting?

Comment: See answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `file_html` function accepts a `resources` parameter, which must be an actual `Resources` object (not a string). For convenience, there are some pre-configured resource objects. In particular, the `bokeh.resources.INLINE` object can be passed to `file_html` to use inline resources.

Comment: Thank You so much. This is very helpful.